# hive select max from a empty table but get one row with value null

Tags: hive

first I create a table in hive:

```
CREATE TABLE `test5`.`meta_increment`  ( 
    `table_name`    string, 
    `date_modified` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("path"="hdfs://myhdfs/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test5.db/meta_increment")
STORED AS PARQUET
TBLPROPERTIES ('numFiles'='1', 'spark.sql.create.version'='2.3.0', 'spark.sql.sources.provider'='parquet', 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1', 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"table_name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"date_modified\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}', 'totalSize'='700')
GO
```

then I execute a query:

```
select max(date_modified) from test5.meta_increment where table_name='shopsNifi'
```

got a result:

```
  _c0
1 null
```

Why there is one row?I think there should be no row,because the table is empty.
(My case is：I want to get the max date of a table,and get incremental data.)

Comment: That's how aggregate functions like `MAX`, `SUM`   etc behave, they return a single row with `NULL` when you run on a table with no records. `COUNT` returns 0 when there are no rows

Comment: Think again: if you had to design a language specification, would you make MAX have different behaviours depending on context?? That would be hell! Besides, you don't have to imagine things, just to use a well-established standard named SQL...

Comment: If you want to hide the fact that you gave an empty table, for whatever reason, just hide it explicitly > `SELECT mx FROM (SELECT MAX(x) mx FROM ...) blah WHERE mx IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thank you all,I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions like AVG, SUM etc are designed in such a way that they return a single column if the table is empty.